# How to map a websphere mq 7 queue to a EJB 3 destinationName

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x, ibm-mq, message-driven-bean

I need to map WebSphere MQ7 queue (Say queA in Queue Manager QMA) to a EJB3 MDB.

I created the MQ Queue Manager and Queue using
`crtmqm QMA` and start it using `strmqm MQA`
Then i wrote a file file name `QMA.conf` and included
`DEFINE QLOCAL ('queA')`
line it and run the command
`runmqsc QMA < QMA.conf`
then I run
`strmqcsv MQA &`
`runmqlsr -m QMA -t TCP &`
All these steps done as mqm logged user.

Then I follow 
http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossEAP5IntegrationwithWebSphereMQ
link and configure RAR to the jboss 5.1. When I run the test connection that also succeeded.

There I include

```
* channel - SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN
* hostName - localhost
* port - 1414
* queueManager - ExampleQM
* transportType - CLIENT
```

and In my MDB I include

```
@MessageDriven( name="WMQMDBTest",
        activationConfig = 
        { 
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="messagingType",propertyValue="javax.jms.MessageListener"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType",propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "queA"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "true"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "channel", propertyValue = "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "hostName", propertyValue = "localhost"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "queueManager", propertyValue = "QMA"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "port", propertyValue = "1414"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "transportType", propertyValue = "CLIENT"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "username", propertyValue = "mqm"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "password", propertyValue = "password")
        }) 
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
@ResourceAdapter(value = "wmq.jmsra.rar")
```

When I try to deploy the bean it says

```
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=integration-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=business-logic-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,  
  name=WMQMDBTest,service=EJB3" is in error due to the following reason(s): 
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: queA not bound
```

Comment: Have you verified that queA actually exists in QMA?  I read that you created a script to define it but not that you verified it exists either by displaying it in runmqsc or by looking at it in WMQ Explorer.

Comment: Yes Queue is available in the WQM.

Comment: Well, that's a start.  Unfortunately that's as far as I go.  I don't see anything in the WMQ parts of this that would prevent your connection and I don't know JBoss config.  The one thing I'll offer is that if you have installed the full WMQ client (instead of just grabbing the jar files) then you can use the sample programs to validate your connection.  If you can use the existing WMQ config to connect using amqsputc then you have narrowed the problem down to the JBoss config.  Of course if all you did was grab the jars then you are EXTREMELY limited as to what diagnostics you can perform.

Comment: I've updated the tags to include [tag:jboss] so this question will get more visibility from that group of folks.  Hopefully that will produce an actual answer.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You've written

> ```
>         @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "queA"),
>         @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "true"),
> ```

with the *useJNDI* property implying that 'queA' is the name under which the JMS Queue is bound into the JNDI namespace - this does not directly correspond to the queue you have defined here

> DEFINE QLOCAL ('queA')

If you want it to refer to a physical WMQ queue on your queue manager then you need the useJNDI property set to false, in which case destination specifies the name of a queue on the queue manager, not a JNDI name. On the other hand, if you do want to use JNDI lookup of Destinations then you need to ensure that the destination name specified matches the Queue definition in the -ds.xml file, e.g.

> ```
>         @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "jms/request")
> ```

would correspond to

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.resource.deployment.AdminObject" name="jca.wmq:name=request_queue">
    <attribute name="JNDIName">jms/request</attribute>
    <depends optional-attribute-name="RARName">jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='wmq.jmsra.rar'</depends>
    <attribute name="Type">javax.jms.Queue</attribute>
    <attribute name="Properties">
        baseQueueManagerName=QMA            
        baseQueueName=queA
    </attribute>
</mbean>
```

note the JNDIName attribute of the mbean corresponds to the destination name